# Installing the Minisom package in Pycharm

Tags: python, installation, pycharm

I'm following this [tutorial](http://glowingpython.blogspot.nl/2013/09/self-organizing-maps.html) to get a better grasp on the concept of SOM. 
This however requires me to install the `Minisom` package.

If i try the normal way of installing a package in Pycharm

1. File->Settings->Project settings->Project interpreter
2. Press on the "+" sign

I don't get any hits on the term "minisom"/"Minisom".

Any thoughts on how else I can install this package?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have selected the right interpreter? because if I try the same steps, works well. 
On the [GitHub](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom) page you can see that the python versions which were been tested are 2.7.3 and 3.2.3. Are you using one of these two?

Anyway, an alternative way to install `MiniSom` is:

1. Download or clone the project following this [link](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom.git)
2. Enter in the directory
3. run `python setup.py install` (may require root privileges)

Let me know.